# How to select the current date row from multiple date rows using system date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with many rows, they contain different dates, any one of them will be for the current period. There is no end date as a field otherwise i would have compared system date between from and to date. I have tried using max function but still it displays many rows.

The data is grouped by a type identifier, so for each type there will be a current date row.

What can be the best query to get the current row (single) which is active considering the current date?

Below is the original query:

```
Select Group1,Group2,FromDate,FPFrom, FpTo FROM [DB].[dbo].[HGD] AS GD, [DB].[dbo].[HDT] AS TD WHERE GD.GRoup1 = TD.MainGroup
```

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM yourTable WHERE procStart <= getdate() ORDER BY procStart DESC
```

or something like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM yourTable row_number OVER(GROUP BY TypeId, Order By procStart DESC) RN WHERE procStart <= getdate()) DQ WHERE DQ.RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks but now it shows only 1 record, as mentioned in the question, there are different types and their current dates

Answer (score 0):

Please try to be more precise. I think you are looking something like shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    SomeDate datetime,
    SomeType int
)
INSERT #temp VALUES
('2016-07-20', 1),
('2016-07-23', 1),
('2016-07-27', 1),
('2016-07-30', 1),
('2016-01-25', 3),
('2016-01-31', 3),
('2016-02-21', 3),
('2016-07-23', 3),
('2016-09-30', 3)

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT SomeDate, SomeType, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeType ORDER BY SomeDate) RowNumber
    FROM #temp
),
Ranges AS
(
    SELECT T1.SomeDate StartPeriod, COALESCE(T2.SomeDate, DATEADD(year,1,GETDATE())) EndPeriod, T1.SomeType
    FROM Numbered T1
    LEFT JOIN Numbered T2 ON T1.RowNumber+1=T2.RowNumber AND T1.SomeType=T2.SomeType
)
SELECT * FROM Ranges
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN StartPeriod AND EndPeriod
ORDER BY SomeType
```

This yields:

```
StartPeriod              EndPeriod                SomeType
2016-07-23 00:00:00.000  2016-07-27 00:00:00.000  1
2016-07-23 00:00:00.000  2016-09-30 00:00:00.000  3
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Paweł Dyl` gave me an idea and I added a condition to my query and got the desired results.

ToDate field was not available , so I created a field by adding 180 days to it.

```
AND GetDate() BETWEEN cast(FromDate as Date) AND DATEADD(DAY, 180,cast(FromDate as DATE))
```

Thanks again.